# MySQL INSERT issue with foreign keys in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I am using PDO to insert values into my table like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Maps(meetingId, street, city, code, centerLat, centerLon, zoom, markerVisible, markerLat, markerLon) VALUES (:meetingId, :street, :city, :code, :centerLat, :centerLon, :zoom, :markerVisible, :markerLat, :markerLon)";

$paramArr = array(
    ":meetingId" => intval($mapInfo['meetingId']),
    ":street" => $mapInfo['street'],
    ":city" => $mapInfo['city'],
    ":code" => $mapInfo['code'],
    ":zoom" => $mapInfo['zoom'],
    ":centerLat" => $mapInfo['center']['lat'],
    ":centerLon" => $mapInfo['center']['lon'],
    ":markerVisible" => $mapInfo['marker']['visible'],
    ":markerLat" => $mapInfo['marker']['lat'],
    ":markerLon" => $mapInfo['marker']['lon']
);

$db = $this->databaseManager ->getDB();
$query = $db->prepare($query);

foreach ($paramsArray as $key => $value) {
    $query->bindParam($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

When I execute this query I get:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

meetingId is foreign key but I add a key that I am 100% sure exists in te relevant table. This key is of type int.

On the other hand if I remove the first variable and type in proper id in its place (that again I am sure exists) I get

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you execute the query with parameters substituted with values in your favourite mysql manager app, then do you get the same error? Are you sure that tge right value is substituted into meetingid parameter? Are there any other foreign keys in the table?

Comment: @Shadow, yes I am sure. When i substitute when doing query manually weverything works fine.

I also found out that when i pass $paramsArray directly to execute statement (instead of binding each param manually in a loop) everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code here:

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $query->bindParam($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

You are declaring that every value you're passing is an integer (`PDO::PARAM_INT`) when that is just not the case, hence the integrity constraint error (the integer didn't match the data in the other table) and then the general error when you "fixed" `meetingId`.

To fix this you do not need the loop to bind, just execute the query with the array:

```
$queryResults = $db->prepare($query);
$queryResults->execute($paramArr);
```

From [Demystifying PHP PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html):

> YOU MUST pass all values to bind in an array to `PDOStatement->execute()` ***or*** you have to bind every value with `PDOStatement->bindValue()`, then call `PDOStatement->execute()` with no parameters.

Comment: Should not make much of a difference.

Comment: You wont belive it.
IT actually did. When I bound one by one I always got integrity constraint issue.
When I did passed array to execute instead everything worked like charm.

I am confused now.

Comment: The update should eliminate the confusion @RobertPorter

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the issues identified in the answer from Jay Blanchard

PDO `bindParam` passes *by reference*, not by value.

So one possible fix for the problem is to to tweak this one line of code:

```
foreach ($paramsArray as $key => $value) {
```

to add a **`&`** character before `$value`, to make it a reference **`&$value`**

```
foreach ($paramsArray as $key => &$value) {
                                 ^
```

That should be sufficient to fix the code.

---

Or, you could just use the **`bindValue`** function rather than the **`bindParam`** function. That's what's happening in the answer from Jay Blanchard.  (Passing the values as an array on the `execute` is equivalent to **`bindValue`**.)

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php